# OnOptionsItemSelected is not called in fragment xamarin android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

In OnCreate:
SetHasOptionsMenu (true);

```C#
public override bool OnOptionsItemSelected(IMenuItem menu)
        {
            menu.SetChecked (true);
            switch (menu.ItemId) {
            case Resource.Id.selecta:
                Toast.MakeText (Application.Context, "Top", ToastLength.Long);

                return true;
            case Resource.Id.selectb:
                Toast.MakeText (Application.Context, "New", ToastLength.Long);

                return true;
            }
            return base.OnOptionsItemSelected (menu);

        }
        public override void OnCreateOptionsMenu(Android.Views.IMenu menu,MenuInflater inflater)
        {
            //MenuInflater.Inflate (Resource.Menu.Action_menu, menu);
            //menu.Clear();
            inflater.Inflate(Resource.Menu.Action_menu,menu);

            base.OnCreateOptionsMenu (menu,inflater);
        }
```

When the item of checkbox is checked . OnOptionsItemSelected is not called.

Comment: Is there a OnOptionsItemSelected-Method in your Activity too? This could be the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have a implementation of `OnOptionsItemSelected` in your Activity too.

Either remove it or return `false` if you want to give Fragment a chance to handle this event.

The Activity gets a chance to handle this event first. So `onOptionsItemSelected()` is called first on the Activity before the method is called for the fragment. Only if it is not handled by the Activity then the fragment has a chance to handle it.

Comment: In Activity has OnOptionsItemSelectd to open drawerLayout.

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the code from your Activity's OnOptionsItemSelected-Method?

Comment: I fixed it. But I want default of checboxA is checked in OnActivityCreated

Comment: If I understand you correctly, it would be a good idea to open another question for this. People who know the answer will find it easier.